# xmrig runtime dll crash

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining, miners, xmrig

I am trying to compile xmrig as a dll file, i compile it correctly as an executable downloading the source from  [here](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/tree/master/src) .  For compiling it to dll, I use cmake and run these commands similarly to what i do for executable `.exe` [here.](https://xmrig.com/docs/miner/build/windows)

Dll commands:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -DXMRIG_DEPS=c:\xmrig-deps\msvc2017\x64 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE
cmake --build . --config Release
```

I also changed the name of the `add_executable()`function in `cmakelists.txt` to `add_library()`for compiling as a dll.

In my dll, i have this source code, that i downloaded from the  [source](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/tree/master/src) , i only modifed the `xmrig.cpp` file before running the cmake commands to compile as a dll.

```
extern "C"{
  __declspec(dllexport) void some();
}

void some(){

    using namespace xmrig;

    char **argvPass;
    //argvPass[0] = "deneme.exe";
    int argcPass = 1;   

    Process process(argcPass, argvPass);

    const Entry::Id entry = Entry::get(process);
    if (entry) {
        Entry::exec(process, entry);
    }

    App app(&process);

    int x = app.exec();

}
```

My question is, it successfully compiles the dll file and i get `xmrig.dll`, i load the dll file using, `LoadLibrary()` and i call the `some()` function above (which is a modification of xmrig.cpp from the source), the dllloader loads the function, but on the line `Process process(argcPass, argvPass);` it seems to crash, this happens during runtime of the dll. For more illustration, i will put the dll loader.cpp here:

```
int main() {
  HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("xmrig.dll");

  if (hGetProcIDDLL == NULL) {
    std::cout << "cannot locate the .dll file" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "it has been called" << std::endl;
    
  }
  
   
  FARPROC xf = GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "some");
if(GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "printer") == NULL){
    
}else{
    std::cout <<"not null" << std::endl;
}

    std::cout << GetLastError() << " err" << std::endl;
    
    
    xf();
    //getchar();
    //return 0;
}
```

As the executable runs fine with the exact same code, what could be the reason that it crashes at that line? Could it be the arguments that i am passing through the `Process::Process()` function. Can someone please confirm me with this trying to get this done? The dll is very much needed on our side and i would appreciate any kind of help..

Moreover, why does the function fail, maybe it could be due to my Visual Studio version, or due to the arguemnts being passed through, i really want to know. Thank you

Comment: Leaving aside the question of why you'd even want/need the miner as a DLL, you probably get a crash simply because you are passing an uninitialized array (argvPass) to the Process constructor and stating it has 1 element (argcPass = 1).

Comment: @jtgrassie i have reasons

Comment: it got fixed, and that was the reason why it crashed @jtgrassie